# SwipeRefreshLayout gets nulled in a coroutine

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout in my layout, when the it is pulled (setOnRefreshListener) is called, I am using a coroutine to refresh the data in my recyclerview.

It was working as expected but from last few days I am getting some crashes in my Crashlytics with the following log -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: refresh must not be null
   at com.example.fragments.DataFragment$refreshData$1.invokeSuspend + 189(DataFragment.java:189)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith + 33(BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run + 233(DispatchedTask.java:233)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 751(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6816(ActivityThread.java:6816)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1563(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1451(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Here's the `refreshData()` method -

```
private fun refreshData() {
    if (actionMode != null) actionMode!!.finish()
    myAdapter = Adapter(type, this@DataFragment)
    myAdapter!!.setEmptyView(empty_view)
    recycler_view.adapter = myAdapter
    refresh.isRefreshing = true

    //Get the Data List...
    launch {
        delay(1000)
        val dataList = getTheData() //This method uses withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        myAdapter!!.addAll(dataList)
        myAdapter!!.toogleEmptyView()
        if (refresh.isRefreshing) refresh.isRefreshing = false //This is where the crash occurs, according to Crashlytics
    }
}
```

I am using `kotlin-android-extensions` so there is no `findViewById()`

Comment: Are you sure you have the right import in this class for synthetic with same name as layout file ?

Comment: Yes, the crash doesn't occur on my devices as well as emulators.

Comment: After `delay(1000)` there might be a chance that this controller (Fragment of Activity) is no longer Alive or attached to Window .. So i guess you should Check the state before accessing UI elements directly if this is the case .

Comment: even if I use `refresh?.isRefreshing = false`, it would still be `null` and I won't be able to hide the refreshing state.

Comment: You are accessing the UI asynchronously. This means that, as @ADM is saying, maybe the Activity or Fragment is no longer alive when you try to access it. There is no "refreshing state" to hide if there is no UI. I guess you could easily reproduce the bug by closing the Activity/Fragment just as `refreshData()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up on using `synthetic` layout in my fragment as I couldn’t make it work.

I also tried accessing the variable like `this@DataFragment.refresh`, thinking maybe the variable was in a coroutine scope so it wasn't accessible (but it should have been, as the `CoroutineContext` was `Dispatchers.Main`) but that didn’t work too.

Finally using the same old `rootView.findViewById()` in the `onViewCreated()` method & it doesn't throw that Exception anymore.

Answer (score 0):

this error related to your layout i mean when you use kotlin-android-extensions you must always make sure imort right xml in top of you kotlin file.

Check this options

**1)** Sometime you have same id in two diffrent layout like refresher so this can make crash. You check this refresher is the same that in you layout or not (you can click cntr + B on refresher)

**2)** Sometime you create two diffrent layout for diffrent Api like above 21 so in some device that are below 21 this error happens.

I hope it helps. If i remember more i wrote down

Comment: I said in the comments above that I am using the right import, also there’s only one layout file.